# C++ string centering alignment

Tags: visual-c++

```
std::vector<std::string> voters;

void LogVoters()
{
    if (voters.size() > 0)
    {
        std::string out;

        out.append("\n"); // newline at start

        std::cout << "Vote results: ";
        for (auto v : voters)
        {
            char formated_string[256];
            std::snprintf(formated_string, sizeof(formated_string), "%s \n", v.c_str());
            out.append(formated_string);
        }
        std::cout << out.c_str();
        voters.clear();
    }
}

int main() { // this gets called multiple times, thats why in voters string vector will be more names
    
    std::string player_name = "IdontNeedName1337"; // some random name
    
    int vote_option         = 0;

    char formated_string[256];
    std::snprintf(formated_string, sizeof(formated_string), "%6s voted %6s", player_name.c_str(), !vote_option ? "YES." : "NO.");
    
    voters.push_back(formated_string);
    
    LogVoters();
}
```

output is like

```
    IdontNeedName1337   voted   YES.
    ElonUsk102   voted   NO.
```

I want

```
    IdontNeedName1337   voted   YES.
    ElonUsk102          voted    NO.
```

I want to center it like this, please help

edit: this is how it works
so please help me god
"
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." anoying

Comment: What do you think "%6s" does?

Comment: `int vote_option` is weird when 0=yes.  Use enums, and prefer to make 0=false=no when it's boolean-like

Comment: I agree that `vote_option` is not related to the problem. I merely thought I'd drop a friendly tip, one programmer to another.  Following standards like 0=false=no helps understandability, and therefore prevents bugs.  But it's possible that your case is more specialized and has a reason for being different, that's fine.

Comment: The code given does [not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aaf67872e7e339e) produce the output given (only one space before "voted").  Please edit the question to contain a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can answer it.

Comment: Yes. If you want explain:
iVoteOption() returns int value in range 0-1.
0 = yes, 1 = no

Comment: Ok, let me edit code

Comment: HERE -> http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fe3ef399ad42a10

Comment: That also only has one space before "voted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code can't produce that output.  Let me make a minimal reproduction of the code you posted to start with:

```
std::snprintf(formatted, 256, "%6s voted YES", "IdontNeedName1337");
std::cout << formatted;
std::snprintf(formatted, 256, "%6s voted NO", "ElonUsk102");
std::cout << formatted;
```

This would produce the result

```
 IdontNeedName1337 voted YES.
 ElonUsk102 voted NO.
```

Which isn't what you say you're getting, since it only has one space before "voted". You say you're getting

```
IdontNeedName1337   voted YES.
ElonUsk102   voted NO.
```

To get that, your minimal code must be something closer to

```
std::snprintf(formatted, 256, "%s   voted YES", "IdontNeedName1337");
//                                ^ change here
std::cout << formatted;
std::snprintf(formatted, 256, "%s   voted NO", "ElonUsk102");
std::cout << formatted;
```

Which isn't what you say you have in your code, so I'm largely guessing here.

I'm not sure what you thought the `%6s` did in the code, since that's basically the answer

```
std::snprintf(formatted, 256, "%20s voted YES", "IdontNeedName1337");
//                              ^ change here
std::cout << formatted;
std::snprintf(formatted, 256, "%20s voted NO", "ElonUsk102");
std::cout << formatted;
```

This tells the formatter to make this entry at least 20 characters wide. By default, it will right-pad with space characters, which matches your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use std::left, std::setw, std::setfill with a stringstream object to format as per your desired output. The sample code and output are given below-

```
    std::string player_name = "IdontNeedName1337"; // some random name
    int vote_option         = 0;

    stringstream str;
    str << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << player_name << std::setw(10) << "voted" << std::setw(10) << (!vote_option ? "YES." : "NO.") << endl; 
    
    cout << str.str(); // prints formated string

    str.str("");
    player_name = "ElonUsk102";
    vote_option = 1;
    str << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << player_name << std::setw(10) << "voted" << std::setw(10) << (!vote_option ? "YES." : "NO.") << endl; 

    cout << str.str(); // prints formated string
```

[image]